# Autorun .EXE files with WINE

Tags: 13.04, windows, wine, games, executable

I am using WINE to run several Windows-only games that I play. Currently, in order to play the game, I must locate the file in Nautilus, right click, and Open with > WINE.  If I lock the .EXE file to the Launcher, then try to run the WINE icon, then nothing happens. If I copy the .EXE Shortcut to the desktop, then I lose the option to right click & open with WINE.

What I would like to be able to do is simply designate all .EXE files to automatically open (on double left-click) with WINE.

I've searched through other questions here and other sites and have been unable to find an answer, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you need is a launch script....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed wine so I can answer this question better.  Once wine finished installing (from Software Center)

[image]

I copied an EXE file over (utorrent.exe)

[image]

The I right clicked the file, and choose Open With --> Wine Windows Program Loader, and it opened.  See image below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wine is not in the list of available applications to Open With. The option to add a program is greyed out.

Comment: Try starting the file browser from terminal with `sudo nautilus` navigate to the file and try setting the default again. I too do not have wine installed.

Comment: I'll install wine and let you know a little later.

Comment: 'sudo nautilus' doesn't seem to do it, but placing the .exe on desktop allows it to work, so problem solved! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

To autorun .EXE files with WINE when you double click on them from your file manager you need to edit `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` file (or `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` to make this change system-wide) and add the following line at the end of the file:

```
application/x-ms-dos-executable=wine.desktop
```

A system reboot is probably necessary.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run this command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo sed -r -i 's/^NoDisplay=(true|false)$/NoDisplay=false/' /usr/share/applications/wine.desktop
   ```
2. Right click on a exe file, open "Properties" and navigate to the "Open with" tab.
3. Locate "Wine Windows Program Loader" in the list and press "Set as default".
4. exe files should now open in Wine by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04
I installed WinRAR in my laptop using wine and I right clicked . exe file then I clicked open with or something like this and I selected WinRAR archiver .

Now I can easily run . exe files with double clicking !!

Sorry if my English is not good